# Input type="datetime-local" is accepting 6 digits for year selection allow 4 digits

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

```js
//current month and year
        var yearNow = new Date().getFullYear();
        var monthNow = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

        //set the start date's field value to current year
        document.getElementById('date-start').value = "01/01/" + yearNow;

        //set the value of the end date field to current date
        document.getElementById('date-end').value = monthNow + "/" + new Date().getDate() + "/" + yearNow;

        $(function () {
            $(".date-picker").datepicker();
        });
```

```html
<label for="date-start">Start Date</label>
                    <input class="date-picker" id="date-start">
                    <label for="end-date">End Date</label>
                    <input class="date-picker" id="date-end">
```

Input type="datetime-local" is accepting 6 digits for year selection allow only 4 digits for year selection.

```html
<label for="date-start">Start Date</label>
                    <input class="date-picker" id="date-start">
                    <label for="end-date">End Date</label>
                    <input class="date-picker" id="date-end">
```

Expected: It should only 4 digits for year selection instead of 6 digits using html, bootstrap, jQuery, JavaScript

Comment: Can you update your snippet to *demonstrate* the issue?   As it is, you just have an `input` and it "accepts" any text.